# iOS - is the user able to restore apps that were removed from the store

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Suppose the following situation:

- A user buys an app
- this app is removed from the store temporarily, by changing the availability date to a year in the future. Note that the app was not deleted from the store, it is just hidden by a change on the availability date.
- the user deletes the app
- the user regrets deleting and wants to restore the app from icloud.

will the user be able to do that? and what about apps that were completely deleted from the store?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is incorrect. Unless you indicate in iTunes Connect that the app was removed for legal reasons (Rights and Pricing section) the user will still be able to re-download the app from iCloud.

[image]

Comment: ahhh, thanks. But what about when the app is temporarily removed by changing the availability date to the future? NOTE:I don't see this option on any of my apps inside Right and Pricing. WIll this appear if I click on "indicate a legal issue with iCloud for this app?"... I don't want to click that and flag my app as having a legal issue... 

Comment: @RubberDuck this should hold true under that circumstance, and this will appear when you deselect all to remove the app from sale.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is not displayed in the app store(developer hide or remove), user can not re-install it after deleting, until developer make it displayed in app store again.
if developer deleted the app completely from app store , that means the app is not displayed int the app store, user can not re-install it yet, but the developer can re-upload the app again using the same app-id.

**Can or not can re-install app depends on whether the app is displayed in app store**

**Also depends on whether it is the same app-id**